# Architecture for CPU intensive tasks with NodeJS & Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, cpu

I'm currently thinking out a NodeJS application where I want to use socket.io for communication between multiple clients.

The application will consist of hundreds of clients which all have a location on a google maps map. I want the server to process for each client, which clients are in a 200 meter radius of each other. If I were to do this all pure in javascript within nodeJS this would put a huge load on the server, and I'm afraid this would cause the server to pause all other tasks while processing this huge task, which would cause all communications to be halted while the server is doing cpu intensive tasks.

My question is, how can one use NodeJS with Socket.io purely for communication between clients, and move the more CPU intensive tasks to somewhere else so that communications between clients are not halted while the server is doing cpu intensive tasks?

Thanks in advance and excuse my english!

Bram

Comment: I feel this question might be a bit broad for a useful answer. Perhaps if you put together a test in Node you can benchmark and evaluate your concerns on multitasking, and ask some more specific questions about your approach?

Comment: It may be worthwhile to (also) look into optimized data structures that will make the query you want to perform less CPU-intensive (for geospatial lookups, [R-Tree's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) are quite common and pretty quick).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a pub/sub worker queue model where the socket.io server just interacts with clients and persists their data to a database (redis or whatever) and a separate cluster of worker processes pull computation jobs off a queue, calculate the results, and write them back, where the client servers can transfer them out to the clients.